# porque no me compara 2 fechas con comparison en cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Esta es la regla que tengo, pero no funciona:

```
$validator
    ->add('end_date', 'comparison', [
          'rule' => ['comparison', 'end_date', '>', 'start_date']
          ])
```

quiero que aparezca que la fecha final sea mayor a la fecha inicial

Answer (score 1):

Como lo haría yo:

en el buildRules de la tabla añadiría la siguiente regla, que llama a una función que les pasas las dos propiedades del entity como parámetro.

```
$rules->add(function ($entity) {
        return $this->dateComparison($entity->end_date, $entity->start_date);
    }, 'dateComparison', [
        'errorField' => 'end_date',
        'message' => __('Is not greater than start date')
    ]);
```

Aquí está la función a la que llamarías:

```
public function dateComparison($startDate, $endDate)
{
    if($startDate > $endDate){
    return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```